# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool' while binding List view

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview, .net-4.5

I try to Bind Checkbox Checked property in side `ListView` Like this :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_holi_sal" runat="server" Class="chk_holi_sal" Checked="<%#:Item.HasSal%>" />
```

---

```
public bool HasSal
{
    get { return SALARY_CALC == 1; }
}
```

---

But I get the following compiler error :

> Compiler Error Message: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'

I check the values of `<%#:Item.HasSal%>` and find it 's equal `True` OR `False`

Why do I get this error all the time ?

---

According to the Answers to use `Eval` instead of take advantage of the `strongly type` value for the `ListView` Control ,I face new exception :

[image]

Comment: use Eval(Item.HasSal)

Comment: As the error code suggests "Checked" is a bool(true or false). Because you have called .ToString() in your eval you have a string. You need to use a bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following line worked with me :

```
 <input id="chk_holi_sal" class="chk_holi_sal" type="checkbox" checked=' <%# Eval("HasSal") %>' disabled="disabled" runat="server" value="<%#:Item.HasSal%>" />
```

I try to use the `strongly-Typed` feature but it fails,I have to use `Eval`.

Answer (score 2):

try with this code

```
<asp:CheckBox  ID="chk_holi_sal" runat="server" Checked="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Item.HasSal")) %>"  />
```

or with ternary operator

```
<asp:CheckBox  ID="chk_holi_sal" runat="server" Checked=
  <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Item.HasSal")) ? true : false %> />
```